# How do I? Magento out of stock simple products, but DO want to show configurable product (out of stock)

Tags: product, configurable-product, layered-navigation, stock

How do I? Magento out of stock simple products, but DO want to show configurable product (out of stock)

(We sell T-shirts, in sizes)

Let me explain

- we have setting show out of stock products to NO
- because layered navigation counted all T-shirt sizes as available (so S would be 10, M would be 10 and L would be 10, instead stock was 6, 8 and 10 resp.) => the solution we received was to set show out of stock products to NO
- Now we have a configurable (new) product that has simple products.
- We set all the simple products to out of stock (so you cant order)
- And set the configurable (new) product to in stock.

The expected behavior would be that we see the configurable (new) product in our store. And when we click on it we cant order it.

The result now is: that the configurable (new) product does not show at all.

**Now our question**: how do we show the the configurable (new) product (with simple products set to out of stock)

---

I think there is a discrepancy here with the layered navigation needing us to select 'show out of stock products to no' when this use case would have as set it to 'show out of stock products to yes'

I hope I wrote i down a little bit clear ... hope you understand

Comment: are you don't want to main the stock for `configurable products`?

Answer (score 3):

Set the simple product Visibility (Catalog->Manage Product->"Select Product"->General) to "Not Visible Individually". Place the simple product to "In Stock" and add Quantity. (Simple products will not show on the front end)

The Configurable product should now show the available simple products. A configurable products inventory is based off the simple product's inventory.

Hope this helps.